# Can't get Mondrian's CmdRunner working

Tags: mondrian

I'm trying to run CmdRunner and stuck with inability to point it to my DB.

I wrote a simple configuration file:

```
mondrian.catalogURL=file://<my schema definition>
mondrian.test.jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://<my server and credentials>
mondrian.rolap.aggregates.generateSql=true
mondrian.rolap.generate.formatted.sql=true
```

And trying to run it as

```
$ ./bin/run.sh -p prop.properties
```

When I execute a query I receive an error `Mondrian Error:Internal error: Error while creating SQL connection: Jdbc=jdbc:odbc:MondrianFoodMart
No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:MondrianFoodMart`. I have no idea where does it take odbc from.

How can I set my own DB URL?

PS I had a lot of trouble just getting it running. Both run.sh and build.sh are broken (at least in sources found [here](https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian/tree/3.10.0.1-R)). Is it generally supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've you found a solution to this problem. I've having the same issue with mondrian 3.11 and I've worked around by setting my jdbc settings in the `mondrian.foodmart.jdbcURL` key.